# Why does vitest mock not catch my axios get-requests?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, unit-testing, vite, vitest

I've been trying out vitest, but I've gotten stuck when i tried to run tests on a component that utilizes the PokeAPI. I figured creating a mock setup would fix it, but to no avail.

The component that has the logic is fairly simple.
Form, with input and submit button where you enter the name of a pokemon and then the result is shown.

```
<template>
  <h1>Pokedex thing</h1>
  <form @submit.prevent="search">
    <!--    Input field and submit button -->
    <input v-model="searchTerm" type="text" placeholder="Search for a Pokemon" />
    <button type="submit">Search</button>
  </form>
  <p v-if="searching">searching...</p>
  <div v-if="searchResult.pokemon && !searching" data-key="pokemon">
    <p>{{ capitalized }}</p>
    <img :src="searchResult.pokemon.sprites.front_default" alt="Pokemon" />
  </div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { reactive, ref, computed } from "vue";
import { AxiosError, AxiosResponse } from "axios";
import axios from "axios";

const searchTerm = ref("");
const searching = ref(false);

const searchResult = reactive({
  pokemon: undefined as { name: string; sprites: { front_default: string } } | undefined,
});

const search = async () => {
  searching.value = true;
  await axios
    ?.get(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${searchTerm.value.toLowerCase()}`)
    .then((response: AxiosResponse) => {
      searchResult.pokemon = response.data;
      searching.value = false;
    })
    .catch((e: AxiosError) => {
      searching.value = false;
      if (e.response?.status === 404) {
        searchResult.pokemon = {
          name: "Pokemon not found",
          sprites: {
            front_default: "https://via.placeholder.com/150",
          },
        };
      }
    });
};

const capitalized = computed(
  () => `${searchResult.pokemon?.name.charAt(0).toUpperCase()}${searchResult.pokemon?.name.slice(1)}`,
);
</script>
```

The test is pretty straight forward. I mounts the component, finds the input, sets the value and presses the button. From there on, i've fallen into despair

```
  it("should search pokemon", async () => {
    const wrapper: VueWrapper = mount(Pokedex);
    const input = wrapper.find("input");
    await input.setValue("bulbasaur");
    await wrapper.find("button").trigger("click");

    await flushPromises();

    const result = wrapper.get("[data-key=pokemon]");

    console.log(result);

    console.log(wrapper.text());
  });
```

For the mocks, i followed the guide from vitest, linked here, and just filled in with the URL's that I used.

```js
//imports etc..
export const restHandlers = [
  rest.get(
    "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/bulbasaur",
    (req: RestRequest, res: ResponseComposition, ctx: RestContext) => {
      console.log("fjkshdgkolsjhglkjsdhg");
      return res(ctx.status(200), ctx.json(testPokemon));
    },
  ),
  rest.get(
    "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/invalid",
    (req: RestRequest, res: ResponseComposition, ctx: RestContext) => {
      return res(ctx.status(404));
    },
  ),
];
// setupServer, beforeAll, afterAll, afterEach.
```

When I try to get the pokemon-div, it throws me an error, saying it doesn't  exist. I figure its because it hasnt been rendered.

I'm new to vitest and I've been trying to google everything that comes to mind, but no luck. I have a feeling, as if the setupServer function isnt working properly.

Comment: Mock axios calls using https://github.com/ctimmerm/axios-mock-adapter.

Comment: You might find the answer here useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72277787/spying-on-mocking-import-of-an-import