# Spying On/Mocking Import of an Import

Tags: javascript, vue.js, unit-testing, ecmascript-6, vitest

I'm writing unit tests using vitest on a VueJS application.

As part of our application, we have a collection of API wrapper services, e.g. `users.js` which wraps our relevant API calls to retrieve user information:

```js
import client from './client'

const getUsers = () => {
   return client.get(...)
}

export default {
   getUsers
}
```

Each of these services utilise a common `client.js` which in turn uses `axios` to do the REST calls & interceptor management.

For our units tests, I want to check that the relevant `url` is called, so want to spy on, or mock, `client`.

I have followed various examples and posts, but struggling to work out how I mock an import (`client`) of an import (`users.js`).

The closest I've been able to get (based on these posts - [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35240469/how-can-i-mock-the-imports-of-an-es6-module), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27323031/how-to-mock-dependencies-for-unit-tests-with-es6-modules)) is:

```js
import { expect, vi } from 'vitest'
import * as client from '<path/to/client.js>'
import UsersAPI from '<path/to/users.js>'

describe('Users API', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
        const spy = vi.spyOn(client, 'default')    // mock a named export
        expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled() // client is called at the top of users.js
    })

    test('Users API.getUsers', () => {
        UsersAPI.getUsers()
        expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled()
    })
})
```

but it's tripping on:

```
 ❯ async frontend/src/api/client.js:3:31
      2| import store from '@/store'
      3| 
      4| const client = axios.create({
       |                              ^
      5|     headers: {
      6|         'Content-Type': 'application/json'
```

where it's still trying to load the real `client.js` file.

I can't seem to mock `client` explicitly because the `import` statements run first, and so `client` is imported inside `users.js` before I can modify/intercept it. My attempt at the mocking was as follows (placed between the imports and the `describe`):

```js
vi.mock('client', () => {
    return {
        default: {
            get: vi.fn()
        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Late to the party but just in case anyone else is facing the same issue.

I solved it by importing the module dependency in the test file and mocking the whole module first, then just the methods I needed.

```
import { client } from 'client';

vi.mock('client', () => {
    const client = vi.fn();
    client.get = vi.fn();
    
    return { client }
});
```

Then in those tests calling `client.get()` behind the scenes as a dependency, just add

```
  client.get.mockResolvedValue({fakeResponse: []});
```

and the mocked function will be called instead of the real implementation.

If you are using a default export, look at the [vitest docs](https://vitest.dev/api/#vi-mock) since you need to provide a default key.

> If mocking a module with a default export, you'll need to provide a default key within the returned factory function object. This is an ES modules specific caveat, therefore jest documentation may differ as jest uses commonJS modules.

Comment: How to do that with typescript, I have an error as my import have not mock methods....

Comment: Not a clue I am afraid, never used typescript

Answer (score 16):

#### Mocking a module

`vi.mock()`'s path argument needs to resolve to the same file that the module under test is using. If `users.js` imports `<root>/src/client.js`, `vi.mock()`'s path argument needs to match:

```js
// users.js
import client from './client' // => resolves to path/to/client.js
```

```js
// users.spec.js
vi.mock('../../client.js')    // => resolves to path/to/client.js
```

It often helps to use [path aliases](https://vitejs.dev/config/#resolve-alias) here.

#### Spying/mocking a function

To spy on or mock a function of the mocked module, do the following *in `test()`*:

1. Dynamically import the module, which gets the mocked module.
2. Mock the function off of the mocked module reference, optionally returning a mock value. Since `client.get()` returns `axios.get()`, which returns a `Promise`, it makes sense to use [`mockResolvedValue()`](https://vitest.dev/api/#mockresolvedvalue) to mock the returned data.

```js
// users.spec.js
import { describe, test, expect, vi } from 'vitest'
import UsersAPI from '@/users.js'

vi.mock('@/client')

describe('Users API', () => {
  test('Users API.getUsers', async () => {
    1️⃣
    const client = await import('@/client')

    2️⃣
    const response = { data: [{ id: 1, name: 'john doe' }] }
    client.default.get = vi.fn().mockResolvedValue(response)
    
    const users = await UsersAPI.getUsers()
    expect(client.default.get).toHaveBeenCalled()
    expect(users).toEqual(response)
  })
})
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-vitest-mock-module-function?file=src%2Fcomponents%2F__tests__%2Fusers.spec.js)

Comment: Thanks so much for such a rich response. I have tried to replicate in our own repository, but still get the same errors.

I have modified the StackBlitz to reflect the same folder structure we have: https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-vitest-mock-module-function-gt3gpq?file=package.json

I don't hit the same error as shown in the stackblitz, we are able to run our test, but we still hit the same issue where it's trying to load the full `client.js` file.

Comment: I've also noticed that in your example, removing `vi.mock('@/client')` doesn't change any behaviour, and the test still passes? Why would this be?

It seems like our issues are stemming from our `client.js` importing a local `vuex` store, which then runs more imports, and so on. My understanding of the `vi.mock` is that it should stub the `client.js` file and prevent it from being loaded? Because the `import UsersAPI..` runs prior to the vi.mock line, I'm assuming this is why the `vi.mock` is not affecting any behaviour here?

Comment: I've added another demo [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-vitest-mock-module-function-nrqerr?file=src/client.js), where it loads a `store/index.js` that I want to prevent loading.

Comment: tvm, faced issue on mocking `axios.get.mockResolvedValueOnce` but that `axios.get = vi.fn().mockResolvedValueOnce` fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I've accepted the above answer, as that did address my initial question, but also wanted to include this additional step I required.

In my use case, I need to mock an entire module import, as I had a cascading set of imports on API files that in turn, imported more and more dependencies themselves.

To cut this, I found this in the vuex documentation about mocking actions:

https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/testing.html#testing-actions

which details the use of webpack and [inject-loader](https://github.com/plasticine/inject-loader) to substitute an entire module with a mock, preventing the source file loading at all.